# Problem writing data on hadoop kerberized using pentaho 7.1

Tags: hadoop, pentaho, kerberos

I'm using Pentaho 7.1 and my goal is to write to the Hadoop database. I'm using the Pentaho "Hadoop File Output" component to try to write to Hadoop. I can not properly create the hadoop cluster, I get these errors after configuring all the parameters:

```
[2018/10/30 23:10:53 - [Named][1] cluster: tst - Root Directory Access: FATAL We couldn't run test Root Directory Access.
2018/10/30 23:10:53 - Named cluster: tst - null
2018/10/30 23:10:53 - Named cluster: tst - java.lang.NullPointerException
2018/10/30 23:10:53 - Named cluster: tst - at org.pentaho.bigdata.api.hdfs.impl.HadoopFileSystemLocatorImpl.getHadoopFilesystem(HadoopFileSystemLocatorImpl.java:62)
2018/10/30 23:10:53 - Named cluster: tst - at org.pentaho.bigdata.api.hdfs.impl.HadoopFileSystemLocatorImpl.getHadoopFilesystem(HadoopFileSystemLocatorImpl.java:49)]
```

The hadoop environment is kerberized. Has anyone managed to write about kerberized hadoop using Pentaho version 7.1?

Thank you so much for your support

Comment: Not clear what you are asking -- Hadoop is not a _database_; you don't _create_ a cluster but try to connect to its distributed file system; the `NullPointerException` suggests that you are missing a number of mandatory client-side properties but you don't explain what properties you have set, nor how you set them, nor what manual/tutorial you have followed...

Comment: If Pentaho has no explicit documentation about Kerberos auth, just follow the Hadoop standards: ask your Hadoop admins for valid `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` client-side conf files, drop these into a local dir, add this **directory** to your Java CLASSPATH, restart your app.